# How to enable "Application Timeline" for UWP app?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a UWP C# app.  I am running the profiling tool in Visual Studio 2015 (Pro Edition) and taking snapshots.  When I open the report the only option enabled is "Memory Usage", but "Application Timeline" is the information that would be useful to me.

The docs I found say it should be available, but it is always grayed out.  How do I enable?

Comment: Is it still grayed out if you uncheck "Memory Usage" in the [tools page](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC850270.jpeg)? "Memory Usage" and "Application Timeline" cannot be run within the single performance session but you should be able to run each of them individually.

Comment: No, enabled now. That was it!  Thanks @AndreyKriachko!!!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. Can you please accept the answer I just published? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Memory Usage" and "Application Timeline" cannot be run within a single performance session. If you have "Memory Usage" tool checked in the [tools page](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC850270.jpeg), please uncheck it.